# optimizing code that writes byte array image to disk

Tags: java, file, io, apache-tika

I have the following code that that writes large images to disk. My application server is running out of memory and I'm wondering if I could somehow optimize the following:

```
public void writeImgToDisk(byte[] base64AttachmentInBytes, String dmxi){

        String destinationAndFileName  = "";
        String fileNameMinusExtension = getCurrentTimeStampForFileNaming();
        String extension="";
        try {


               TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
               InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64AttachmentInBytes);

               MediaType mediaType = config.getMimeRepository().detect(stream, new Metadata());
               MimeType mimeType;


            try {
                mimeType = config.getMimeRepository().forName(mediaType.toString());
                extension = mimeType.getExtension();
                System.out.println("Extension is:"+ extension);

                File folder  = new File("Z:\\images\\"+ sref);
                if (!folder.exists()){
                    folder.mkdir();
                }
                destinationAndFileName  = "Z:\\images\\"+ dmxi + "\\" + fileNameMinusExtension+ extension;

                System.out.println("destinationAndFileName is:"+ destinationAndFileName);
            } catch (MimeTypeException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64AttachmentInBytes);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destinationAndFileName);
            IOUtils.copy(input, output);


            System.out.println("It was written..");  
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This works but its is the cause of a bottleneck during high volume calls.

Comment: CodeReview.stackexchange.com would be a great place for this.

Comment: Rather than having the entire byte array (base64AttachmentInBytes) in memory then loop around `read`ing say 8K of bytes and then writing them.  i.e. use the methods on the `ByteArrayInputStream` directly rather than `IOUtils`

Comment: see first example on this page http://www.studytrails.com/java-io/byte-reading-writing.jsp

Comment: Could I possible get a code snippet explaining what you mean ?

Comment: You're likely running out of memory because you're keeping the entire image, apparently base64 encoded) in memory. This doesn't seem necessary since all you seem to be doing is mime type detection.

Comment: How do you know that this code is causing your out-of-memory and not something else? And if it is this code, you may be doing this concurrently on many threads. Since this is IO-bound, you may end up having a lot of threads running this code. Try limiting the number of threads using a limited-size threadpool - you can't get more concurrency than the speed of your disk in any case.

Comment: you should also profile your app and see where the memory is going before spending too much time optimizing something that may or may not be the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Have you thought about serialization: https://dzone.com/articles/fast-java-file-serialization is a good article. Hear good things about kryo.

Comment: the app doesn't have much else that is controversial besides me keeping this byte array around for too long. It does run on within tomcat and each user triggers an instance. I will run a memory dump and see what I get.

Comment: thanks, I'm looking into Kyro now... not sure what object type TestObject in the example is supposed to be though

Comment: @pvg are you suggesting I should never have made the conversion to base64 in the first place in order to perform mime detection ? or are you saying i should have performed mime detection then discarded the base64 object immediately ?

Comment: @user1917363 I gave Kryo a shot, looks promising but I don't have enough info to make the example work.

Comment: @TobyDerrum That's alright, if you are still interested checkout there github page, maybe this will help you out if you still have issues. https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo (I finally changed my username 900 reputation later so sorry for any confusion)

Comment: @TobyDerrum I'm saying two things - first, take some measurements to ensure your memory problem is where you think it is. Second, if it is the image, you already have the problem at `writeImgToDisk(byte[] base64AttachmentInBytes` - at that point you've read the entire image into memory. Use streaming to avoid this when you receive the request. For high-traffic situations, it's common to fully externalize file upload from the app server altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There are changes for your code:

1. Avoid using IOUtils.copy and control your IO on your own.
2. Test different IO classes for your case and for your machine settings.
3. Follow basic troubleshooting steps as mentioned on this link. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/perftuning-137844.html

I have found choosing a buffer size is important and these tips are super useful to overcome memory bottlenecks:
here are some basic rules on how to speed up I/O:

```
Avoid accessing the disk.
Avoid accessing the underlying operating system.
Avoid method calls.
Avoid processing bytes and characters individually.
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice given by @pvg and @scaryWombat. I stopped reading in the whole file in order just to detect the mimetype. I then used iHarder's Base 64 to decode and write my base64 notation string directly to file in one single swoop.

In order to detect the mimetype i decoded a substring of just the first 100 characters.